# How to handle null value in realm.io?

Tags: realm

from what I see if the value is nil for a property it always throws exception. sometimes i cannot simply set a '' empty string as nil, so what's the solution in realm? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null is now fully supported.

OLD answer:

Supporting nil/NULL is on the roadmap.
Until then there are two workarounds:

1. Add a separate property to indicate if your property is nil.

   ```
   @interface IntObject : RLMObject
   @property NSInteger myProp;
   @property boolean myPropIsNil;
   @end
   ```
2. Wrap your property in an object:

   Object properties (links), can be nil though. So if you need a nullable int property, for example, you can wrap it in a new Realm model, like this:

   ```
   @interface IntObject : RLMObject
   @property NSInteger myProp;
   @end
   ```

   Then anytime you want to have an optional "int" property in your models, you can write this:

   ```
   @interface MyModel : RLMObject
   @property IntObject *optionalMyProp;
   @end
   ```

Comment: though this works it's not natural at all. looking forward to the support of nil value. thanks.

Comment: Is there any date for this feature to be included??

Comment: Unfortunately no official dates we can share yet. But it's being worked on actively at the core engine level.

Comment: Note: if you want to be able to sort by your property value, don't use the wrap workaround (2) since there is no support for multilevel keypath sorting.

Comment: Absolutely! Null values has been supported for a while now :-)