# Storing null values in realm using Android

Tags: android, realm, nullable

Previously, when there was no stable version of realm for Java (Android), we could not store null values in realm and we had to perform some unnatural hack to be able to do so, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458585/how-to-handle-null-value-in-realm-io).

But as of now realm 1.0 is released, are there any update about being able to  store null value?

For example : unfortunate cases when there is no field in JSON which I want to store in realm after parsing but haven't handled it manually.

I have the following code:

```
realmObject.setData(jsonObject.getString("SELECTOR"));
```

the program flow stops and exits the block the code is located inside.

the logcat shows

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for SELECTOR

But when I do:

```
realmObject.setData(null);
```

The program flow does not stop and continues across my realm statement  `realmObject.setData(null);`

In some cases, there is no value for the tag "SELECTOR" in my Json file. 
And I want it to be null in default.

Comment: it is store null if no value there for selector,isn't it?

Comment: yeah ,  but when i do so program flow does not go past  that line

Comment: As per now i am detecting the flow with log infos

Comment: is there any error logged? pass your logcat.

Comment: It just skips the block (in my case is loop and  continues from next index ) and its just warning  the logcat prints W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for SELECTOR

Comment: so basically issue is with JSON not with realm as you get json exeption @LaxmanBhattarai

Comment: Yeah i suspect the same now

Comment: shall i delete the question?

Comment: No just update it. that you get jsonexeption that you already do i think :)

Comment: But there are a lot of question about jsonexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found out that the problem is actually with just  :

```
jsonObject.getString("SELECTOR")
```

not the whole statement:

```
realmObject.setData(jsonObject.getString("SELECTOR"));
```

so the fix for me was

```
realmObject.setData(jsonObject.optString("SELECTOR"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [has](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) that will check whether key is available of not and basis of that save value to realm object

```
 if (jsonObject.has("SELECTOR")) {
       realmObject.setData(jsonObject.getString("SELECTOR"));
    }
else{
 realmObject.setData(null);
}
```

Comment: I found a better solution :) we can use optString instead of getString